# Unhandled Runtime Error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am having an issue by using js-cookie package in nextjs. I setup store using context api. and my initial state is

```
const initialState = {
  darkMode: Cookies.get('darkMode') === 'ON' ? true : false,
  cart: {
    cartItems: Cookies.get('cartItems')
      ? JSON.parse(Cookies.get('cartItems'))
      : [],
  },
  userInfo: Cookies.get('userInfo')
    ? JSON.parse(Cookies.get('userInfo'))
    : null,
};
```

cart and dark mode is working fine but userInfo is undefined. It gave me this error
[image: Here is the screenshot]

Here is my login.js page code

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import Layout from '../components/Layout/Layout';
import NextLink from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import {
  Typography,
  Button,
  List,
  ListItem,
  TextField,
  Link,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import useStyles from '../utils/style';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Store } from '../utils/store';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

const Login = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { redirect } = router.query;
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(Store);
  const { userInfo } = state;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (userInfo) {
      router.push('/');
    }
  }, []);

  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const classes = useStyles();

  const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const { data } = axios.post('/api/users/login', { email, password });
      dispatch({ type: 'USER_LOGIN', payload: data });
      Cookies.set('userInfo', data);
      router.push(redirect || '/');
    } catch (err) {
      alert(err.response.data ? err.response.data.message : err.message);
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  };
  return (
    <Layout title='Login'>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler} className={classes.form}>
        <Typography component='h1' variant='h1'>
          Login
        </Typography>
        <List>
          <ListItem>
            <TextField
              variant='outlined'
              fullWidth
              id='email'
              label='Email'
              inputProps={{ type: 'email' }}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            ></TextField>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem>
            <TextField
              variant='outlined'
              fullWidth
              id='password'
              label='Password'
              inputProps={{ type: 'password' }}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            ></TextField>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem>
            <Button variant='contained' type='submit' fullWidth color='primary'>
              Login
            </Button>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem>
            Do n0t have an account? &nbsp;
            <NextLink href='/register' passHref>
              <Link>Register Here</Link>
            </NextLink>
          </ListItem>
        </List>
      </form>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Kindly help me to resolve this issue. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It seems like `Cookies.get('userInfo')` doesn't return a string(serialized object). Could you add `console.log(Cookies.get('userInfo'))`  before creating `initialState` variable ?

Comment: It is giving undefined

Comment: This is the reason you get the error. You don't have this specific cookie; therefore, you can't parse it.

Comment: Although my cart and darkMode is working perfectly. What will be the solution of this.

Comment: You should debug the area of your code where you set up the cookie. Your `POST` call to the API is asynchronous and there should be an `await` before making a request. 

`const { data } = await axios.post('/api/users/login', { email, password });`

Also, don't forget to serialize the data before setting it to the cookie.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `Cookies.set` in second argument you pass `object` and it will be save like this `[object%20Object]`, but it must be a `string`.
First you must convert `object` to `string` by `JSON.stringify()` and then set to cookeis.

```
Cookies.set('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: Recommendation: Always use `JSON.parse` or  `JSON.stringify` with `try/catch` block

Comment: Its already in try catch block

Comment: I have debug all my code but main problem is the js-cookie package. There is something very terrible with this package but i am not getting it

Comment: It’s not about package, problem with data which you set to cookies

Comment: I have serialize the data too but it gave me the same error.

Comment: It was the cached issue. I cleared the cache and now its working perfectly

Comment: This had to be done first before adding edits to the code